# PHP MySQL Query Returning Rows Very Slow

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem with a MySQL query. When ever I run this query it takes over 10 seconds to return the rows. However if I change my limit to 29 it returns it in less than 1 second. My Question is my implementation and query in good shape, or am I making a mistake here that would cause this issue?

```
<?

try
        {
            $con = mysql_connect("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX","XXX","XXX");
            if (!$con)
                {
                    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }

            mysql_select_db("bis_co", $con);

            $query = "SELECT Name, Value FROM `bis_co`.`departments` LIMIT 31"; 

            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo $row['Name'] . "<br />";
            }


        mysql_close($con);
        }
    catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e;
        }
?>
```

Comment: How many rows does the table have?

Comment: Try executing this on directly your MYSQL DB and show us the output:
`EXPLAIN SELECT Name, Value FROM bis_co.departments LIMIT 31`

Comment: @ulvund It has 51 Records Right now. @Virendra running that returns `1 SIMPLE Departments ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 51` With the Columns being id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra(which isnt null but has no value)

Comment: You should add Indexes to your table. It seems you don't have any indexes on your table.

Comment: even without indexes it shouldn't give such bad speed

Comment: i think here can be problem with connection to db. Check time of each function to see where is trouble.

Comment: @Virendra, I usually do index tables, but this problem seems to go outside of that. I have tried to add an index before and still receive the same slow speeds.

Comment: Where are you measuring the time taken by query in PHP or MySQL? If MySQL and you check the time it took to execute both the queries?

Comment: I am measuring them in Both actually. On the server it self, when I run the query I get normal times returned. But when I run it from PHP I get the slow results. And it only happens when its over 30 rows.

Comment: It is a strange query, requesting a limited number of rows without telling MySQL which ones you want "Give me 31 rows, I don't care which ones". Are you sure it's really what you meant?

Comment: Try using "SELECT Name, Value FROM `departments` LIMIT 0, 31"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try getting rid of the

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

statement. The **if** statement will take care of returning the array. You could also change the query string to

```
"SELECT Name, Value FROM `departments` LIMIT 31"
```

since you're already setting the database name in the mysql_select_db statement. Though, none of these should be causing your issues. It seems like it's a table issue. Have you tried it with mysqli and prepared statements?